# Swift and Objective C Delegate calling - Data type issue

Tags: objective-c, swift, types, delegates, int

I try to use a Swift class in Objective C and let the Objective C class "GameScene" receive delegate calls from the swift class. But from within the swift class I get the error "Cannot Invoke drawTopEdge with an argument list of type '(int, col:int)'

```
    //above in the code
    var maze:[[Int]]!
////////////////
     func display() { //this is in the swift class
        for i in 0..<y {
            // Draw top edge
            for j in 0..<x {
                print((maze[j][i] & 1) == 0 ? "+---" : "+   ")
                if ((maze[j][i] & 1) == 0) {
                   delegate!.drawTopEdge(j, col: i) //Error see picture attached and above
                }
            }


    //This is in the GameScene class
    -(void)drawTopEdge:(NSUInteger)r col:(int)c; 
    -(void)drawLeftEdge:(NSUInteger)r col:(int)c;
    -(void)drawBottomEdge:(NSUInteger)r col:(int)c;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVLEe.png

[image]

Comment: did you attach picture?

Comment: int is different than nsuinteger. Did you try by making all int?

Comment: Everything is already in int isn't it?

Comment: but one of the method parameter is nsuinteger

Comment: Ah thanks for the notice. I did change it but I still get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84737/discussion-between-cocos2dbeginner-and-t-77).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)drawTopEdge:(NSUInteger)r col:(int)c;
```

`NSUInteger` becomes `Int` in Swift. However, `int` becomes `CInt`. Ideally you should change your signatures to use `NS*` based integers so that Swift can easily bridge them. But otherwise, you can cast at the calling point:

```
delegate!.drawTopEdge(j, col: CInt(i))
```

See [Dealing with C APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-ID17) and [Foundation Data Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61) for more.

Comment: I changed everything to NSUInteger but I still get the compile errors.

Comment: Ah got it.  Had to use NSInteger.